# How to backup sqlite database and videos in Android app?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-backup-service

I have an SQLite database in my application that stores some simple text data and video file paths.  I would like a way for the user to backup this information, but I am stuck on how to export the actual videos with the database. The database only stores the file paths for the videos, and those are bound to change during the backup process.  What is the bast way to backup both the database and the videos?

Comment: Are these paths linking to existing websites with videos or paths to videos that come along with your app?

Comment: They are file paths to videos stored on the phone taken by users.

Comment: This will be tricky, since paths of videos will be changed when exported, so the paths in the sqlite database should be updated as well.